# What are the restrictions on substitution of terms in Hilbert-style calculus vis-à-vis intuitionistic logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, intuitionistic-logic, hilbert-calculus

I apologize if the title of this question can be better formulated, but I recently encountered a situation where what I thought was valid substitution led to an incorrect thing—at least I think.

I was trying to show myself why double negation elimination is not a theorem but how triple negation and single negation are equivalent. The former, $\neg\neg C \rightarrow C$, can be symbolized as

$((C \rightarrow \bot) \rightarrow \bot) \rightarrow C \tag{1}.$

which is just a special case of

$((C \rightarrow B) \rightarrow B) \rightarrow C \tag{2}.$

The latter, $\neg\neg\neg A \leftrightarrow \neg A$, can be symbolized as

$(((A \rightarrow \bot) \rightarrow \bot) \rightarrow \bot) \leftrightarrow (A \rightarrow \bot) \tag{3}.$

which is a special case of

$(((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow B) \rightarrow B) \leftrightarrow (A \rightarrow B) \tag{4}.$

I thought it was valid to substitute $C$ for $(A \rightarrow B)$ in $(4)$ which would then reduce $(4)$ to

$((C \rightarrow B) \rightarrow B) \leftrightarrow C \tag{5}.$

Obviously assuming $(2)$ isn't a theorem means that $(5)$ can't be proven thereby contradicting the fact that triple negation is equivalent to single negation.

Does this mean that one can never substitute "across" connectives?

**Edit**

It's important to state that the reason I settled to prove the general forms (which is obviously much stronger than special cases) is due to an answer by [Rob Arthan](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2453533/triple-negation-in-intuitionistic-logic) where it seems to me that he has a proof of $(4)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because $((C \rightarrow B) \rightarrow B) \leftrightarrow C$ can't be proven in general doesn't mean it can't be proven for particular values of $B$ and $C$.

The problem is that you have the implication backwards. If we have a proposition with a free variable $P(x)$ that's provable, then for any particular value $A$ (modulo variable capture), P(A) is also provable (by substitution). This implication doesn't go the other direction. That means when we negate, we *don't* get the implication "if $P(x)$ is not provable, then $P(A)$ is not provable". We *do* have the implication "if $P(A)$ is not provable, then $P(x)$ is not provable".

Comment: According to [Rob Arthan](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2453533/triple-negation-in-intuitionistic-logic), $(4)$ is provable which is equivalent to $(5)$, no? I understand that not being able to prove something for the general case doesn't mean it can't be proven for specific cases. I should admit that I don't entirely understand Rob's syntax which is why I specified Hilbert calculus.

Comment: Why do you think $(4)$ is equivalent to $(5)$? The implication goes $(5) \to (4)$ but not vice versa.

Comment: Because I'm extremely ignorant in formal logic especially intuitionistic logic, lol. Without getting technical—I know that violates the very nature of a formal logic—I am treating substitution as a form of "equality" and thus thought $(4) \rightarrow (5)$ as well. Thank you very much for highlighting the source of my problem. This is yet another example of my escaping the formal nature of logic by taking a "shortcut" by relying on my intuition if that makes sense. I'll work more on the basics.

Comment: On a slight tangent, do you believe I should just delete this question? I don't want to "rob" you of reputation points, but I don't want to contribute to "garbage" either. I feel like my ignorance is preventing me from being able to accurately assess the quality of this question.

Comment: @basketballfan22 if asking the question helped you understand something new, it's probably worth keeping.